# NSUserdefaults - How to use objectforkey in Swift 2.2 Xcode7

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to read an array that I saved in NSUserdefaults.
Most of the examples on how to use "objectforkey" or "arrayforkey", which both throws "AnyObject" are giving error in Swift 2.2.

This:

```
    if let array NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mykey")
```

says that cannot use AnyObjet

This:

```
    let array NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mykey") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]()
```

crashes the app saying that is "out of scope"

This:

```
    func readArray() -> NSArray {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("NewsDescriptions")!
}
```

also crashes.

Can someone help me how to read arrayforkey which is AnyObject like objectforkey

Comment: don't save arrays or big object to nsuserdefaults

Comment: Is the missing = a typo? As in `let array = ...`

Comment: You are trying to cast it as a Dictionary

Comment: The second one you are forcing unwrap and using a different key

Comment: Btw arrayForKey returns `[AnyObject]` not NSArray

Comment: @WarrenBurton in the original is not missing, only when I wrote the code here

Answer (score 0):

Save Array:

```
let array:[String] = ["one","two"]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "array")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Retrieve Array:

```
if let retrievedArray:[String] = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("array") as? [String]{
    print("\(retrievedArray)")
}
```

Comment: Well, finally it worked but the output is wrong. It gives me only one of the items and 4 times. I'm saving like you instructed, and I use a string.append to add items to the array, then it only records the last item appended 4 times. For example I have String[orange]... apple.append...output:[apple][apple][apple][apple]. Should be [orange, apple]

Comment: the array is correct, it is being appended with items, but no more than 2 or 3 strings

Comment: So the array is being saved as [orange, apple] and being retrieved as [apple, apple] ?